# KeyboardAwareScrollView not works when focused on multiline TextInput in IOS

Tags: react-native

I have tried with KeyboardAwareScrollView and KeyboardAvoidingView but not affected by keyboard.

My view structured look like below :

```
<KeyboardAwareScrollView
<View>
<View>
   <TextInput/>
</View>
</View>
```

This structure perfectly worked in Android.